# Is "The amount by which something has changed length." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

The full sentence is,
"Strain:  The amount by which something has changed length, measured as a percentage of its original length."

Shouldn't it be incorrect?, or else please explain further, thanks!

From : http://www.aleckassociates.co.uk/glossary-of-structural-engineering-terms/

Comment: oh, I didn't express myself well enough I guess.
Let me edit that.

Comment: It is correct, but does seem slightly awkward.  If I were to change anything, it would be to add one small word: "the amount by which something has changed *in* length, measured as a percentage of its original length."

Comment: @cobaltduck.
Yeah, I too thought that it would be better if it has _in_ .
So, "Something has changed length." (without _in_)  is grammatically correct?

Comment: Why not "it's" instead of "in"?

Comment: I don't find 'changed length' that odd to be honest. It had a length, now it changed. 'In' could be used to distinguish between strain in lenght and width, but when length is the only direction something can stretch in in this example, it looks fine as is.

Comment: Rather than present it as a definition, why not recast the whole sentence as one which introduces the concept of strain - ie. a convenient nondimensional measure of deformation expressed in percentage, decimal fraction, or parts-per notation. Mathematically, strain is defined as needed to solve the problem at hand. Please don't tie the concept to a single instance of usage when first introducing the idea. Here's what it looks like when you get into it a bit more. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_strain_theory

Comment: In terms of *English* there is nothing grammatically wrong. In technical terms, it is incorrect: strain is not a percentage. You *can* express it as a percentage, but it is not *required*. For example, if a rod is 100cm long, and it is stretched to 120cm long, it's strain is (120-100)/100 = 0.2. This can also be expressed as 20%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds perfectly fine to me, as it is a technical definition (they tend to be more formal), except I would say *expressed as a percentage* rather than *measured as a percentage*.

You measure in (whatever) units and convert to percent.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence is trying to use a relative pronoun phrase to restrict the referent of a preposition.  It means:
'Strain is the amount that something has changed it's length by ___.'
People are sometimes uncomfortable with a final preposition, so they try to move it along with the relative pronoun.  Since 'that' has other meanings (demonstrative), 'which' is used instead.

Comment: That's not exactly what the sentence means.